# MySQL in clause string to array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, where-clause

I saw many similar questions some how i could not find my answer. Here is the deal. I have two tables. I'm trying to find a way to stimulate a text array into in-clause.

```
table.list    table.user
+--------+    +--------+
|id|list |    |id|name |
+--+-----+    +--+-----+
| 1|1,2,3|    | 1|jack |
+--+-----+    +--+-----+
| 2|6,8  |    | 2|john |
+--+-----+    +--+-----+
              | 3|jane |
              +--+-----+
              | 6|jim  |
              +--+-----+
              | 8|jade |
              +--+-----+
```

Here is my lovely piece of in-clause code.

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user.name) 
          FROM user WHERE user.id in (list.list)
       ) 
FROM list;
```

My question is is there any way to convert list.list to an array. I know the difference. Normally it should be like in (1,2,3) or ('1','2','3') but now i have ('1,2,3'). Any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13011/8)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE list
    (`id` int, `list` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO list
    (`id`, `list`)
VALUES
    (1, '1,2,3'),
    (2, '6,8')
;

CREATE TABLE user
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO user
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'jack'),
    (2, 'john'),
    (3, 'jane'),
    (6, 'jim'),
    (8, 'jade')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user.name) 
 FROM user WHERE instr(concat(' ,',list.list,','),concat(',',user.id,',')) > 1
 ) 
FROM list
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13011/8/0)**:

```
jack,john,jane  
jim,jade
```

Comment: It worked, can you explain how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You should add another table to create the link between `list.id` and `user.id`. It is not a good idea to use comma separated lists in a database. They are extremely hard to operate on and are much slower than joining well indexed tuples.

If a user can only exist in one list then it would be best to add an additional column to `user`. Otherwise if user could exist in multiple lists then you would use something like the following.

```
list    user          user_to_list
+--+    +--------+    +---------------+
|id|    |id|name |    | userId|listId |
+--+    +--+-----+    +-------+-------+
| 1|    | 1|jack |    |      1|1      |
+--+    +--+-----+    |      2|1      |
| 2|    | 2|john |    |      3|1      |      
+--+    +--+-----+    |      6|2      |
        | 3|jane |    |      8|2      |
        +--+-----+    +-------+-------+
        | 6|jim  |
        +--+-----+
        | 8|jade |
        +--+-----+
```

You can also read more on Database Normalization on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).